# How to return values to a named range instead of using a range's Offset()

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

Warning to the experts: I am a “pre-beginner” in vba...

I have a workbook that I am using to find attributes of a product based on its name. E.g. cell in named range “Album_Name” with value “My Favorite Things by John Coltrane” should return a value of “John Coltrane” in named range “Musician”, a value of “Jazz” in named range “Music_genre” (**offset from named range “Album_Name by 78 columns**), etc.

I’m currently using this:

```
Sub UpdateAttributes()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim vezesQueEncontrouNumero As Integer
    Dim posicaoSegundoNumero As Integer

    For Each c In Range("Album_Name", Range("Album_Name ").End(xlDown))

    vezesQueEncontrouNumero = 0
    posicaoSegundoNumero = -1

    For i = 1 To Len(c)

        If IsNumeric(Mid(c, i + 1, 1)) Then
            vezesQueEncontrouNumero = vezesQueEncontrouNumero + 1
            If (vezesQueEncontrouNumero) = 2 Then
                posicaoSegundoNumero = i
            End If
        End If
    Next
**If InStr(UCase(c.Value), UCase("John Coltrane")) > 0 Then c.Offset(0, 78).Value = "Jazz"**
```

My question:
As the number of attributes is growing it gets more difficult to “c.Offset” by the correct number of columns. And as sometimes I must add columns in between, it really gets unworkable! Is there a way of putting **c.Value in a named range instead of using Offset**?

Thank you.

---

**Update**

After the help of @Luuklag , @wallyeye , @JvdV and - specially - @nwhaught I've rewrote my vba but still to no avail. I'm still missing something. The vba changes the value of the cell in the same column ("name") and not in the "Genre" or "Artist" column. (I did put "name" at A1, "Genre" at B1 and "Artist" at C1). Somehow the "attribution" of "colNum" isn't working.

```
    Sub UpdateProductAttributes()

    Dim colNum As Integer
    For colNum = 1 To 100 'or however many populated columns you end up having...
        Select Case Sheet1.Cells(1, colNum) 'Look at the column header
            Case "Genre" 'If you've found the "Genre" column
                genreColumn=colNum 'Give the genreColumn variable the correct value
            Case "Artist"
                artistColumn=colNum
        End Select
    Next

   Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim vezesQueEncontrouNumero As Integer
    Dim posicaoSegundoNumero As Integer

    For Each c In Range("name", Range("name").End(xlDown))
    vezesQueEncontrouNumero = 0
    posicaoSegundoNumero = -1
        For i = 1 To Len(c)

            If IsNumeric(Mid(c, i + 1, 1)) Then
            vezesQueEncontrouNumero = vezesQueEncontrouNumero + 1

            If (vezesQueEncontrouNumero) = 2 Then
            posicaoSegundoNumero = i

            End If
            End If

    Next i

        If InStr(UCase(c.Value), UCase("Coltrane")) > 0 Then
            c.Offset(0, genreColumn).Value = "Jazz"

            ElseIf InStr(UCase(c.Value), UCase("Brad Spreadsheet")) > 0 Then
            c.Offset(0, genreColumn).Value = "Indie Folk Grunge"

        End If
        Next c
End Sub
```

***What could be wrong?***

Comment: use index match, to arrive at the appropriate column.

Comment: Thank you @Luuklag. Could you please provide an example/sample code? I've never used index match...

Comment: When I have to program to specific columns like this, I set up specific column variables, then reference them in code. Depending on how dynamic the columns are, I’ll make them constants or assign them by examining the headers at the start of the routine. I.e. colMCat = range.find(“music category”).column   Just shorthand here, not the specific syntax. As a side note, I hope you are maintaining a list of the cross references in a sheet somewhere, not just putting them in your code.  You are doing great for a pre-beginner!

Comment: Something you could try implement is getting the column number through match as mentioned before. In this example the value has to be present `ColNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SearchValue, Sheets(1).Range("1:1"), 0)`

Comment: Commenting on edit: you've got your assignments backwards. Rather than colNum = genreColumn, it should be genreColumn=colNum. :-)

Comment: You are offsetting from c, but c won’t be column zero. Instead use something like cells(c.row, genreColumn).value = ...

Comment: I would also like to reiterate, you shouldn’t have your artists and genre names in code, they should be in a lookup table.  It gets unwieldy very quickly in code, and you cannot easily manipulate them.  I would have them on a second sheet, load them into an array and build a dictionary object.  Something like arrArtists = sheet2.range(“a2:b99).value.  Set scpArtists= New scripting.dictionary   ScpArtists.comparemode = textcompare. For lngrow=lbound(arrArtists,1) to ubound(arrArtists,1).  ScpArtists.item(arrartists(lngrow,1))=lngrow. Next lngrow.  Then as you look through your data you can

Comment: Just say if ScpArtists.exists(c.value) then cells(c.row,genreColumn) = arrArtists(ScpArtists.item(c.value),2)

Comment: You have to set a reference to the Microsoft scripting runtime to use the dictionary object.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions @wallyeye . I'm afraid your suggestions are too advanced for my current level of knowledge of vba. But I'll give it a go and try to figure out how to implement them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on some of the comments: 
Index Match is a pattern that's generally used in in-cell formulas as a more-flexible companion to VLOOKUP.

It works like this: `=INDEX(YourTotalRangeOfData,MATCH("YourSearchKey",TheColumnRangeOfYourSearchKey,0),TheNumberOfTheColumnInYourTotalRangeThatYouWantToReturn)`

In practice, it looks like this: `=INDEX(C3:E11,MATCH("Frantz",B3:B11,0),2)`

In cells, Excel will keep track of the changes for you. In code, you'll continue to run into issues with changing column reference numbers.

wallyeye's comment about setting column variables is a good one, and you could do it like this:

```
Dim genreColumn as Integer
genreColumn = 78

**If InStr(UCase(c.Value), UCase("John Coltrane")) > 0 Then c.Offset(0, genreColumn).Value = "Jazz"**
```

Even better, in my opinion, would be to have a "setup" section that ran at the beginning of your code. The purpose of the setup section is to set all of your column variables for you. Something like:

```
Dim colNum as Integer
For colNum = 1 to 100 'or however many populated columns you end up having...
    Select Case Sheet1.Cells(1, colNum) 'Look at the column header
        Case "Genre" 'If you've found the "Genre" column
            genreColumn = colNum 'Give the genreColumn variable the correct value
        Case "Artist"
            artistColumn = colNum
    End Select
Next
```

Run that at the beginning of your code, and you'll never have to worry about the changing column position again. As long as you have the title of the column correct (which is much easier to check) you'll have the correct number.

Also, to echo what others have said, you're doing great. This doesn't look like the code of a "pre" beginner. :)

Comment: This seems to be an elegant solution @nwhaught!

Comment: I did as you said (or at least I think I did) @nwhaught but it doesn't seem to work. It changes the value of the cell in the same column. Somehow the "attribution" of "colNum" isn't working. I did put "name" at A1, "Genre" at B1 and "Artist" at C1.

Comment: Do some debugging to see what exactly is wrong. Put some breakpoints in the code in the select statement. Ctrl+g will pull up the "immediate window", and with the code paused you can try various things to see what your code is actually doing. For example: "?Sheet1.Cells(colNum, 1).value" will show exactly what's currently being tested in the select statement.

Comment: Oof. I feel silly. I mixed up my rows and columns...should be Cells(1, colNum). Editing my answer to reflect.

Comment: it still doesn't work... Do you think there might be any other problem?

Comment: I just copied the edited answer and tried it with "Genre" in A1 and "Artist" in B1, and did a debug.print genreColumn , which returned 1, and a debug.print artistColumn, which returned 2. That's what I'd expect. What are you seeing in your debugging?